# elementary row ops to find inverse of matrix

Tags: matrices

I am trying to find the inverse of matrix through elementary row operations but I'm a bit stuck if someone could guide me? Thank you 
[image]

\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 : 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 5 & 1 : 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    3 & 9 & 4 : 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{matrix}

So far I have tried the following Row operation R2 <- R2 - 2R1 which got me to

\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 : 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 : -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    3 & 9 & 4 : 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{matrix}

and then another row operation of R3 <- R3 - 3R1  which got me to

\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 : 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 : -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 4 : -3 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{matrix}

but I am unsure how to continue or if i"m on the right track.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You're on the right track. The next thing I would do is subtract 3 of R2 from R3 to get a 0 0 1 row. Then go back through and subtract this new row 3 from R2 until it's in the form 0 1 0. Then subtract R2 from R1 to get it into a 1 0 0 form.

Comment: You lost a $1$ at the bottom of the last column.

Comment: oh thank you Christopher. I just got a bit confused I guess. So is it just like I've got to just test out which operations would work or is there a sort of method I could follow to help? And thanks chris for pointing that out , my mistake.

Comment: Just work column by column,  getting a $1$ on the diagonal,  then use it to clear the rest of the column.  When you're done the inverse will be on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply row operations to the left side of the matrix until it becomes the identity matrix. Once this has happened, the right hand side will be the inverse of what was originally the left hand side.

We can use your first two steps, although you seem to have lost a $1$ on the bottom right.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&:&1&0&0\\2&5&1&:&0&1&0\\3&9&4&:&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$R_2 \to R_2 - 2R_1$ and $R_3 \to R_3 - 3R_1$

(We can do these two steps at the same time since they don’t interfere with each other)

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&:&1&0&0\\0&1&1&:&-2&1&0\\0&3&4&:&-3&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$R_3 \to R_3 - 3R_1$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&:&1&0&0\\0&1&1&:&-2&1&0\\0&0&1&:&3&-3&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$R_2 \to R_2 - R_3$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&:&1&0&0\\0&1&0&:&-5&4&-1\\0&0&1&:&3&-3&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$R_1 \to R_1 - 2R_2$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&:&11&-8&-2\\0&1&0&:&-5&4&-1\\0&0&1&:&3&-3&1\end{bmatrix}$$

So the inverse you were seeking is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}11&-8&-2\\-5&4&-1\\3&-3&1\end{bmatrix}$$